# return a value from a socket in flutter

Tags: flutter, sockets

I wrote a void function that allows me to have the data of a socket of a nodejs server like this one

```
  Future<void> getCoordinate() async{
    //call socket
    GeocoordinateModel geocoordinateObject;
    Map<String,dynamic> geocoordinateMap;
   IO.Socket socket = IO.io(url,OptionBuilder().setTransports(['websocket']).build());
   socket.on("connect", (data) => {
     socket.on('geocoordinateData',(message)=>{
       if(message){
         geocoordinateMap = Map<String,dynamic>.from(message['payload']),
         geocoordinateObject =  GeocoordinateModel.fromMap(geocoordinateMap),
         print(geocoordinateObject),
       }
  }),
  });

  //return geocoordinateObject;
  }
```

now, now I would like to return the varibla geocoordinateObject of the function
i try this code, but it it didn't work

```
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:real_chat/data/model/geocoordinate_model.dart';
import 'package:socket_io_client/socket_io_client.dart' as IO;
import 'package:socket_io_client/socket_io_client.dart';
class GeocoordinateApi {
  static const String url = 'https://xxx.herokuapp.com/';
  Future<GeocoordinateModel?> getCoordinate() async{
    //call socket
    GeocoordinateModel? geocoordinateObject;
    Map<String,dynamic> geocoordinateMap;
   IO.Socket socket = IO.io(url,OptionBuilder().setTransports(['websocket']).build());
   socket.on("connect", (data) => {
     socket.on('geocoordinateData',(message)=>{
       if(message){
         geocoordinateMap = Map<String,dynamic>.from(message['payload']),
         geocoordinateObject =  GeocoordinateModel.fromMap(geocoordinateMap),
         print(geocoordinateObject),
       }
  }),
  });

  return geocoordinateObject;
  }
}
```

but it returns null

Comment: Can you provide all your imports? Not sure where `IO.io` is from.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I had done the imports. with the void function, I find the data with a print, but I would like to return these data. is it possible to return these data? or I will have to settle for the void() function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [completer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Completer-class.html) to create your own future.

#### Steps

1. **Instantiate a completer**

```dart
final completer = Completer<GeocoordinateModel?>();
```

2. **Complete the completer**

```dart
completer.complete(geocoordinateObject);
```

3. **Return the future**

```dart
return completer.future;
```

#### Code

```dart
Future<GeocoordinateModel?> getCoordinate() async {
  GeocoordinateModel? geocoordinateObject;
  Map<String, dynamic> geocoordinateMap;
  IO.Socket socket =
      IO.io(url, OptionBuilder().setTransports(['websocket']).build());
  // [NEW CODE]: Add a completer
  final completer = Completer<GeocoordinateModel?>();
  // You don't have to listen for 'connect'.
  socket.on(
    'geocoordinateData',
    (message) => {
      // if(message) doesn't check for null. It should be if(message != null).
      // If this is null safe code, you don't have to check for null.
      geocoordinateMap = Map<String, dynamic>.from(message['payload']),
      geocoordinateObject = GeocoordinateModel.fromMap(geocoordinateMap),
      // [NEW CODE]: send your object to the completer.
      completer.complete(geocoordinateObject);
    },
  );

  // return the future.
  return completer.future;
}
```